# How can I return only one field in a mongo array of objects without removing rest of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am querying a collection and in that collection I have an array of objects. In that array I want to use projection to only return one field in every object. However, I do not want to remove all the data outside that object.

Let's say one document in the collection looks like this

```
{
  "a": "some val",
  "b": "some other val",
  "c": [
    {
      "d": "some array val",
      "e": "some other array val"
    }
  ]
}
```

And let's say I want to remove every field in the array besides 'd' and end up with

```
{
  "a": "some val",
  "b": "some other val",
  "c": [
    {
      "d": "some array val",
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
db.collection.find({}, { "c.d": 1 })
```

but this removed "a" and "b" as well and just returned:

```
{
  "c": [
    {
      "d": "some array val",
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, I cannot do:

```
db.collection.find({}, { "c.e": 0 })
```

because there may be other fields besides 'e' and those should be hidden as well.

Comment: Can you try `db.collection.find({}, { a: 1, b: 1, "c.d": 1 })` ? or `a` and `b` just represent something unknown and you just want to focus on filtering `c` array ?

Comment: `a` and `b` are unknown and I want to focus on filtering `c`. In the actual collection there are also many more fields than `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to overwrite existing field and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform `c` array and take only `d` values, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            c: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$c",
                    in: { d: "$$this.d" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```